# How to integrate Gmail, Google contacts and Google calendar into Unity without Thunderbird or Evolution?

Tags: unity, contacts, gmail, google-calendar

I want to integrate my Google contacts, calender and Gmail to Unity. And I don´t want to use Thunderbird or even worse Evolution.

Is there a possibility like in GNOME 3.xx? A lightweight contact / calendar / mail app (maybe one app for contact, one for calendar) would be welcome.

Edit: I want to use the calender to sync my appointments with google - e.g. I open my "ubuntu-calender", make a new appointment and it syncs with google calendar. Also return way.

The same with contacts. I want a see and edit all my contacts in an app and have them sync with google.

Gmail: A notifyer would be enough - just one click on the notifyer and it opens googlemail in chrome. Otherwise an lightweigth email client.

Kind regards
mpm

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide more detail what you want to accomplish with this app.  Do do just want a repository to backup your g-mail and contact information?  How do you wish to use this information with the app (if its not for e-mail)? "I don´t want to use Thunderbird or even worse Evolution"

Comment: For Gmail you could use the lightweight mail client [Geary](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187045/how-do-i-integrate-gmail/187065#187065)

Comment: I would only use calendar if it worked, but it doesn't.  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - July 2017.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu’s New Web Apps Feature of Ubuntu 12.04 & 12.10. This will allow you to integrate your `Gmail` and `Google Calender` to the desktop, and make them first class citizen on your computer. This will allow for system notification pop-ups, HUD integration, and other Unity features. This is how to install it:

Open the `Terminal` and type these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webapps/preview
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-preview
```

Now log out and log back in for the change to take affect. The time next you visit `Gmail` or `Google Calender` on `Firefox` or `Chromium`, they will ask if you want to integrate with the desktop.

Here is some more reading on the subject:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/ubuntu-unveil-new-web-apps-feature-for-12-10

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/list-of-that-websites-support-unitys-new-web-apps-feature

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/how-to-install-ubuntus-new-web-apps-feature

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that this is still beta software.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, for me at least - after installing the packages, neither Firefox nor Chrome ask me if I want to use it. Is it still supported? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I will NEVER change my repositories for any reason.  If it can't be done by normal methods I do not want it on my production systems.  nIt would simply add more documentation workload to make sure it is another page of documentation for each and every system's configuration for security audits.  And those pages would require audits of the repositories.  No way.  Nu-huh.   Period.  I would have a revolt on my hands if I allowed anything like this in our shop.

Answer (score 1):

For calendar try plasma-widget-googlecalendar 
For gmail you should find only notifiers (gnome-mail, gmail-notify, gnome-mail-notifier, checkgmail, gm-notify, unity-mail, etc..) or mail clients (claws-mail, balsa, postler, and so on).
For Contacts, I'm afraid you can find only Unity Lens, as you can read here: http://iloveubuntu.net/unity-contacts-lens-brings-ubuntu-one-and-google-contacts-dash

Just a couriousity: why not Evolution/Thunderbird?

Comment: You should elaborate on your answer and name the specific appliclations you are refering to.  The questioner is asking a specific question

Comment: Thx to jasmines. I´ll give them a try. I don´t like tb / evol. - it´s to much for me - and it doesn´t integrate with google mail (like archive the mails..)

Answer (score 0):

Install gnome-gmail then run it and will integrate with the system. Run "System Settings" -- "Details" -- "Default Applications" -- click the drop down for "Mail" and select "Gnome Gmail". Your browser will now open to read email at Gmail. After restarting the system click the Mail indicator and the item that says "Setup mail..." will open your browser with Gmail as the active tab. I don't run any local email packages so I don't really need integration with them for web based Gmail Contacts and Google Calendar. Evolution and Thunderbird have the facility to integrate with Google applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can sync Gmail with GNOME Mail, Google contacts with GNOME Contacts, Google Calendar with GNOME Calendar Applet Indicator and Google Tasks with the GNOME Tasks Applet Indicator. You can do more research on each of these tasks.

Comment: And all of these integrate with **Unity**?

Comment: You gave the answer, shouldn't you elaborate more, rather then sending the person off after making brief suggestions?

Comment: Downvoting this. It's not nice to send people elsewhere.

Comment: This is just an opinion statement.  No facts here.   Nothing to see.  Move on.

Answer (score 0):

To get (among other things) pop-up windows for google-calendar reminders, with the option to dismiss or snooze the pop-up, see https://bitbucket.org/edgimar/gcalcli . Here are some quick instructions to run the program / install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gdata gxmessage mercurial
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/edgimar/gcalcli gcalcli-repo
cp gcalcli-repo/gcalclirc.example ~/.gcalclirc
```

Now modify `~/.gcalclirc` so it contains data for your preferred way of authenticating to your calendar.  Finally, to run the pop-up daemon, type: `./gcalcli-repo/gcalcli remind` -- for (several) more command-line options, just type `./gcalcli-repo/gcalcli` with no arguments.

To be able to snooze your pop-ups, replace `gxmessage` in `~/.gcalclirc` with `/path/to/gcalcli-repo/extra/reminderpopup` .

Answer (score 0):

To setup Gnome Evolution with Two-Factor-Authorization (2FA) enabled on your account and/or Google for Business, using the IP instead of `imap.gmail.com` might be necessary if Evolution keeps asking you to login with 2FA.

Recommended configuration that works with 2FA and Google for Business:

1. [Enable IMAP in your GMail settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#settings/fwdandpop)
2. [Create a new app password for your Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/apppasswords)
   *(save this somewhere)*
3. In a terminal, run `ping imap.gmail.com` and copy the IP address
4. Create a new Email Account in Evolution *(File -> New -> Mail Account)*

   Full Name: `<your full name>`
   Email Address: `<your full email address>`
   Uncheck `Look up mail server details based on the entered e-mail address`

   Server Type: `IMAP`
   Server: `<the ip address you got in step 3>`
   Port: `993`
   Username: `<your full email address>`
   Encryption method: `TLS on dedicated port`
   Authentication: `Password` **(!)**

   Receiving Options: To your preference

   Sending Email, Server Type: `SMTP`
   Server: `<the ip address you got in step 3>`
   Port: `465`
   Check `Server requires authentication`
   Encryption method: `TLS on dedicated port`
   Authentication Type: `PLAIN` **(!)**
   Username: `<your full email address>`

   When prompted for your password, enter your app password, **not** your Google password.
5. Create a new Calendar in Evolution *(File -> New -> Calendar)*

   URL: `https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/<your email address>/events/`
   User: `Your full google account (user.name@domain.com)`
   Check `Server handles meeting invitations`

   Click "OK" and enter your app password, **not** your Google password.