# wunderlist not execuring on ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: 12.04, wunderlist

I am having some trouble with wunderlist in ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

I followed the instructions on 
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/how-to-install-wunderlist-in-ubuntu.html
and
http://support.wunderlist.com/customer/portal/questions/63885-ubuntu-11-1-installation-?new=63885

It seemed to have installed on my system, the icon is available in my menu.
However when I click to run the app it does nothing.

When I try to run the app through terminal with 
/opt/Wunderlist-1.2.4/Wunderlist

I get this response
/opt/Wunderlist-1.2.4/Wunderlist: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

And that is where the files where installed in, unless I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking on one of my systems which package provide the shared library mentioned returns

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libgtk2.0-0: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
```

So you probably have to run

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
```

to install the shared library that wundelist complains missing...

Edit:
Turned out the link on the Wunderlist website points by default to the 32bit version of Wunderlist. On a 64bit system (as you have), it's better to use the 64bit version of Wunderlist, which is just a little bit hidden: https://s3.amazonaws.com/wunderlist/wunderlist-1.2.4-linux-64.tgz
Using this version and the method described in the links in your post, we got it working!

Comment: Will this affect my system in any way?

Comment: Just ran the code and got the following

libgtk2.0-0 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libunistring0:i386 libgomp1:i386 libcroco3:i386 libgettextpo0:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.

Comment: Ok, so we need to dig a little deeper! You have to make sure that wundelist finds the library and that the library is of the right flavor (32bit). Please paste the output of `ldd /opt/Wunderlist-1.2.4/Wunderlist` and `file /opt/Wunderlist-1.2.4/Wunderlist`, if available

Comment: Did you download the 64bit version of wunderlist? You are using a 64bit ubuntu 12.04 and the default link at the wunderlist website points to a 32bit version (at least for me). The 64bit link is [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/wunderlist/wunderlist-1.2.4-linux-64.tgz)

Comment: linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7749000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf772a000)
 libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
 libatk-1.0.so.0 => not found
 libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0xf75d2000)
 libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => not found
 libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf7538000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xf7504000)
 libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
 libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => not found
 libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => not found
 libpango-1.0.so.0 => not found

Comment: libcairo.so.2 => not found
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xf74b3000)
 libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xf74ae000)
 libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0xf74ab000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf74a2000)
 libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0

Comment: (0xf73a9000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf72c3000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7297000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7279000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf725e000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf70b9000)

Comment: /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf774a000)librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf74a2000)
 libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf73a9000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf72c3000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7297000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7279000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf725e000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf70b9000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf774a000)

Comment: libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf70a2000)
 libselinux.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0xf7083000)
 libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xf706b000)
 libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xf7041000)
 libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xf703a000)
 libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xf6ffd000)

Comment: that is the out put of ldd /opt/Wunderlist-1.2.4/Wunderlist

Comment: Got it, so you've installed the 32bit version, since the library it finds are 32bit libraries, e.g. `libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf772a000)`

Comment: /opt/Wunderlist-1.2.4/Wunderlist: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0x588f6a045f482bca773da7a1258eaa403b4d2137, not stripped - The output of file /opt/Wunderlist-1.2.4/Wunderlist

Comment: I see within the download I have there is both 32 and 64 and one install script, funny that it would detect 32 and install that on a 64 bit system

Comment: To make it work you probably have to install 32bit versions of the libraries that are "not found". Or try to install the 64bit version of Wunderlist. Do you have the ia32-libs already installed?

Comment: I should have if i can recall correctly, but i am not 100% sure

Comment: So I would propose to use the 64bit version from https://s3.amazonaws.com/wunderlist/wunderlist-1.2.4-linux-64.tgz and then continue with the script, better, the exact steps mentioned in your question. The script you are referring to just makes Wunderlist work, as far as I understood it did not directly downloaded the program.

Comment: I will try this and post back here when the download is compete. The fogger way could work for me as well, only problem I am concerned about is when I lose connection and cant access my lists.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4551/discussion-between-ceage-and-marchosius)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to installing Wunderlist:

First you will need to install `Fogger`. You can install it by clicking on the button below.

[image: Install via the software center]

Then you will need to go to this [site](http://visuex.com/blog/25-fogger/60-wunderlist-fogapp-for-ubuntu-1204-released) and follow these instructions.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Within the customization process they talk about a .js and a .css file, where do i get these files? i cant seem to find them? Edit - Scratch this, found it

Comment: Just one thing, do I have any off line functionality with this method?

Comment: I think you won't. What `Fogger` does, is get a website, and integrate it with the desktop.

Comment: loading the website every time I want to use it could be a bit redundant at times, specialy when my connection is slow.

Comment: Where will i be able to find info on how to remove a Fogger app I have made? I forgot to add the icon the setup and wish to redo the setup of it

Comment: If you go into `Preferences` on the `Fogger`, you can delete it from there.

Comment: Awesome! This will be great way to setup fast access to google+ facebook And other web apps that dont have any desktop or linux programs, thank you for this!

Comment: For deeper Facebook integration for Ubuntu, look for my answer on this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138241/how-to-integrate-gmail-google-contacts-and-google-calendar-into-unity-without-t/177214#177214)